# SharePoint randomly displays web part error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, web-part

I am noticing that on all pages sometimes SharePoint doesn't load web part and displays the following message:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator.

Refreshing the page solves this problem.

And another weird behaviour I noticed today. Let's say I have a page in which I have placed Content Editor web part.
I open the page and do not turn of my computer and go home. Next day when I check that page again (I don't refresh it, nothing, it's just there already opened which I did yesterday) it shows the above web part error message.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have the Minimal Download Strategy feature enabled (e.g. a default Team Site)?

Comment: No it's a publishing website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a generic error message. And a generic answer would be - it is happening as it takes to long to load a query.
In order to see the limit of a query timeout you can run powershell command:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.XSLTTransformTimeout
```

If it is 1 sec, you may want to change it to 5 (or whatever you think is reasonable). Use the powershell command:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.XSLTTransformTimeout = 5
$farm.Update()
```

If that won't help you have to try to find if there is anything specific that causes the timeout error. In my case it was a SharePoint bug - if you backup/restore a site collection,  you get this error when displaying All Items views. I created a view loading 20 items at a time instead of all and it fixed the issue.